# React router and createMemoryHistory in test: Property 'location' does not exist on type 'History' when history is defined in beforeEach

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am testing a navbar component that uses React Router. I am trying to use `createMemoryHistory` from the `history` package to test browser navigation.

I am using `react-router-dom v 6.3.0` and `history v 5.3.0`

My test looks like this:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import { NavBarComponent } from "../navBarComponent";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";


describe("<NavBarComponent/>", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ["/"] });
    render(
      <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
        <NavBarComponent></NavBarComponent>
      </Router>
    );
  });
  describe("Clicking on buttons to change route", () => {
    it("navigates to correct paths", () => {
      expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/"); // <----- IDE error is here: Property 'location' does not exist on type 'History'
      userEvent.click(screen.getByText("Collection"));
      expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/collection");
    });
  });
});
```

Running the test gives the following error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

      36 |       //   </Router>
      37 |       // );
    > 38 |       expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/");
```

However, when I break out the `beforeEach` code into each individual test, the test works fine:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import { NavBarComponent } from "../navBarComponent";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

describe("<NavBarComponent/>", () => {
  describe("Clicking on buttons to change route", () => {
    it("navigates to correct paths", () => {
      const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ["/"] });
      render(
        <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
          <NavBarComponent></NavBarComponent>
        </Router>
      );
      expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/");
      userEvent.click(screen.getByText("Collection"));
      expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/collection");
    });
  });
});
```

My IDE indicates that the type of `history` when it is defined in the test itself is `MemoryHistory`, and that is also the type when it is defined in `beforeEach`.

However, accessing the `history` object inside of a test when it was defined in `beforeEach` indicates that the type is `History`, not `MemoryHistory`.

What's going on here? Why does the type seem to change when the object is defined in `beforeEach` as opposed to inside the test itself?

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE shows the correct hint. You declare a constant 'history' with what 'createMemoryHistory' returns in another lexical scope (beforeEach hook). Thus, the 'history' variable inside of the test is something absolutely unrelated. In fact, it is a global object 'history' that is available through web APIs ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)). Would you call your variable in the beforeEach hook anything else, like 'myHistory', it would be simply 'undefined' inside of the test.

What you should do is move the declaration of 'history' to the outer scope, where it will be available for all tests. For example, under the first 'describe'. If you need to recreate it for each test, you can declare it as a 'let' and reassign it in beforeEach hook.